# программа не отвечает pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]при вводе правильных данных и нажатии кнопки ok программа не отвечает

Первый скрипт:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime
from interface import *
import sys
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
from playsound import playsound

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(544, 447)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e;")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 551, 441))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.alarmClockTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.alarmClockTab.setObjectName("alarmClockTab")
        self.deleteButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.alarmClockTab)
        self.deleteButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 360, 41, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.deleteButton.setFont(font)
        self.deleteButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: #fb5b5d;\n"
                                        "border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                        "color: white;")
        self.deleteButton.setObjectName("deleteButton")
        self.addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.alarmClockTab)
        self.addButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 360, 41, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.addButton.setFont(font)
        self.addButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: #fb5b5d;\n"
                                     "border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                     "color: white;")
        self.addButton.setObjectName("addButton")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.alarmClockTab)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 521, 341))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.alarmClockTab, "")
        self.watchTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.watchTab.setObjectName("watchTab")
        self.timeLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.watchTab)
        self.timeLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 110, 190, 57))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.timeLabel.setFont(font)
        self.timeLabel.setStyleSheet("color: #fb5b5d;")
        self.timeLabel.setObjectName("timeLabel")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.watchTab, "")
        self.timerTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.timerTab.setObjectName("timerTab")
        self.timerlabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.timerTab)
        self.timerlabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 110, 190, 57))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.timerlabel.setFont(font)
        self.timerlabel.setStyleSheet("color: #fb5b5d;")
        self.timerlabel.setObjectName("timerlabel")
        self.timerStartButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.timerTab)
        self.timerStartButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 240, 191, 41))
        self.timerStartButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: #fb5b5d;\n"
                                            "border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                            "color: white;")
        self.timerStartButton.setObjectName("timerStartButton")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.timerTab, "")
        self.stopWatchTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.stopWatchTab.setObjectName("stopWatchTab")
        self.stopWatchLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.stopWatchTab)
        self.stopWatchLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 110, 190, 57))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.stopWatchLabel.setFont(font)
        self.stopWatchLabel.setStyleSheet("color: #fb5b5d;")
        self.stopWatchLabel.setObjectName("stopWatchLabel")
        self.stopWatchStartButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.stopWatchTab)
        self.stopWatchStartButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 240, 191, 41))
        self.stopWatchStartButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: #fb5b5d;\n"
                                                "border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                                "color: white;")
        self.stopWatchStartButton.setObjectName("stopWatchStartButton")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.stopWatchTab, "")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.deleteButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "-"))
        self.addButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "+"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.alarmClockTab), _translate("Dialog", "Будильник"))
        self.timeLabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "12:34:12"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.watchTab), _translate("Dialog", "Часы"))
        self.timerlabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "00:00:00"))
        self.timerStartButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Запустить таймер"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.timerTab), _translate("Dialog", "Таймер"))
        self.stopWatchLabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "00:00:00"))
        self.stopWatchStartButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Запустить секундомер"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.stopWatchTab), _translate("Dialog", "Секундомер"))

class Ui_createAlarmClock(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Cancel", self)
        self.cancel.setGeometry(350, 140, 93, 28)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("JetBrains Mono")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.cancel.setFont(font)

        self.ok = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Ok", self)
        self.ok.setGeometry(250, 140, 93, 28)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("JetBrains Mono")
        self.ok.setFont(font)

        self.nameEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.nameEdit.setGeometry(180, 10, 261, 22)

        self.nameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Название", self)
        self.nameLabel.setGeometry(10, 10, 111, 21)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("JetBrains Mono")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.nameLabel.setFont(font)

        self.timeLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Время", self)
        self.timeLabel.setGeometry(10, 40, 111, 31)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("JetBrains Mono")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.timeLabel.setFont(font)

        self.timeEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.timeEdit.setGeometry(180, 50, 261, 22)

        self.melodyLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Мелодия", self)
        self.melodyLabel.setGeometry(10, 80, 111, 31)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("JetBrains Mono")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.melodyLabel.setFont(font)

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(180, 90, 261, 22)

        self.errorLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("", self)
        self.errorLabel.setGeometry(10, 140, 221, 21)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("JetBrains Mono")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.errorLabel.setFont(font)
```

Второй скрипт:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime
from interface import *
import sys
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
from playsound import playsound


class createAlarmClock(Ui_createAlarmClock):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(400, 178)
        self.setWindowTitle("Создание будильника")
        self.con = sqlite3.connect('Базы данных\\alarmClocks.db')
        self.params = {}
        self.select_melodies()
        self.ok.clicked.connect(self.addRow)
        self.cancel.clicked.connect(self.cancel_func)
        self.show()
        self.exec()

    # Добавляет мелодии в comboBox
    def select_melodies(self):
        req = """SELECT id, ringtone FROM Melodies"""
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        for value, key in cur.execute(req).fetchall():
            self.params[key] = value
        self.comboBox.addItems(list(self.params.keys()))

    def cancel_func(self):
        self.close()

    # проверяет правильно ли введены данные
    def valid_data(self, times):
        return self.timeEdit.text() not in times and self.nameEdit.text().strip() != '' and \
               len(self.timeEdit.text()) == 8 and int(self.timeEdit.text()[0:2]) <= 23 and \
               int(self.timeEdit.text()[3:5]) <= 59 and int(self.timeEdit.text()[6:8]) <= 59

    def play_alarm_clock(self, name, alarm_time, id_melody):
        alarm_hour = int(alarm_time[0:2])
        alarm_min = int(alarm_time[3:5])
        alarm_sec = int(alarm_time[6:8])
        con = sqlite3.connect('Базы данных\\alarmClocks.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        melody = cur.execute(f"SELECT ringtone_directory from Melodies WHERE id = {id_melody}").fetchone()
        while True:
            now = datetime.now()
            current_hour = now.hour
            current_min = now.min
            current_sec = now.second
            if alarm_hour == current_hour and alarm_min == current_min and alarm_sec == current_sec:
                playsound(melody)
                break

    # Добавляет будильник в таблицу
    def addRow(self):
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        times = cur.execute("SELECT time FROM alarmClocks").fetchall()
        times = [i[0] for i in times]
        if not self.valid_data(times):
            self.errorLabel.setText("Неверно введены данные")
            self.nameEdit.setText('')
            self.timeEdit.setText('')
        else:
            req = f"""INSERT INTO alarmClocks(name, time, melody_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"""
            cur.execute(req, (self.nameEdit.text(),
                              self.timeEdit.text(),
                              self.params.get(self.comboBox.currentText())))
            self.con.commit()
            self.loadTable()
            self.close()
            self.play_alarm_clock(self.nameEdit.text(), self.timeEdit.text(),
                                  self.params.get(self.comboBox.currentText()))
            self.con.close()

    # Загружает таблицу
    def loadTable(self):
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        result = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM alarmClocks').fetchall()
        ex.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(result))
        ex.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(result[0]))
        for i, elem in enumerate(result):
            for j, val in enumerate(elem):
                ex.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(str(val)))
```

Comment: при вводе правильных данных и нажатии кнопки ok программа не отвечает скорее всего что-то в методе addRow в классе createAlarmClock помогите пожалуйста

Comment: предложил правку на изменение отображение кода)

Comment: @sigalgleb,  спасибо так лучше)